# Module based project structure angular

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm a newbie angular developer.
I've searched many many project structure as a result then I create a module base structure but i'm not sure this approach

My  created a project structure as below;

```
-src
-app
    -components
        -header
        -left-side
        -custom-select
        ... and more component here 
        **components.module.ts**
    -pages
        -home
        -login
        -not-found
        ... and more page here 
        index.ts
        **pages.module.ts**
     -services
        APIService.ts
        LoadingService.ts
        LocalStorageService.ts
        PagesService.ts
        SweetAlertService.ts
        ... and more page here 
        index.ts
        **services.module.ts**
    -models
    -interfaces 
    -data
    ... others 
    app-routing.module.ts
    app.component.html
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
-assets
-environments
... others
index.html
```

more detail and source [code here](https://github.com/ahmeturganci/angular-stack)

Is that a good solution for lose complex app.modules?

Comment: No. You should group by functional features, not by technical layer.

Comment: So Can i fix my structure project or I have to create new one ? @JBNizet

Comment: Not sure how you could fix it without creating a new one...

Answer (score 2):

[As Angular style guide says:](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#folders-by-feature-structure)

> Folders-by-feature structure
>
> Style 04-07
>
> **Do** create folders named for
>   the feature area they represent.
>
> **Why?** A developer can locate the code and identify what each file
>   represents at a glance. The structure is as flat as it can be and
>   there are no repetitive or redundant names.
>
> **Why?** The LIFT guidelines are all covered.
>
> **Why?** Helps reduce the app from becoming cluttered through organizing
>   the content and keeping them aligned with the LIFT guidelines.
>
> **Why?** When there are a lot of files, for example 10+, locating them is
>   easier with a consistent folder structure and more difficult in a flat
>   structure.
>
> **Do** create an NgModule for each feature area.
>
> **Why?** NgModules make it easy to lazy load routable features.
>
> **Why?** NgModules make it easier to isolate, test, and reuse features.
>
> For more information, [refer to this folder and file structure example](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#file-tree)

An example of file structure:

[image]

Comment: can i modifier my exist project?

Comment: @errorau if this project has just one contributor, then you can edit, otherwise you can talk with team about modifying a project structure.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach:

```
App
    - coreModule : all singleton services
    - featureModule1
        -component1
        -component2
        -services
    -featureModule2
    -sharedModule: all reusables components between modules
```

Answer (score 1):

Modules are components that enable LazyLoading.

So i Will recommend you create one Module per "widget" that could be fitted into a lazy loaded strategy.

Also read about Smart components and presentation components for best practices on reusable presentational components.